How do I use android native classes with the GluonFX mobile plugin?
I'm new to gluonfx. I followed the docs and created a new project by using maven.
I was able to compile everything successfully. Now I would like to use some classes from the android sdk (I would like to import for example android.os.Vibrator).
My goal is to implement ads by using the admob sdk in a JavaFX application and at the same time be able to use android classes like Toast and Vibrator.
This is how my pom.xml file looks like:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gluonapplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>gluonapplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>GluonApplication</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>21</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.19</attach.version>
        <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.24</gluonfx.plugin.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication</mainClassName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

What dependencies do I need to add? What do I need to do?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Vibrator is already used by the VibrationService in Gluon Attach: https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/tree/master/modules/vibration, so you can add it to your Java code and use the API that ultimately invokes android.os.Vibrator. For other implementations, you'll need to create a similar service, like in https://github.com/gluonhq/attachextended

@JoséPereda I agree but is there a way to directly use android classes? Is there a way to add android dependencies to the pom.xml file?

No, that is the point of having Attach/AttachExtended: that is the way of "mixing" Java/JavaFX/GraalVM on one side with Java/Android on the other, providing JNI communication between the two different VMs.

@JoséPereda Oh I see, how about adding ads to a javafx application (using admob)?

Before Attach/GluonFX, there was Charm-Down for the old JavaFXPorts plugin, and it had an admob service, but it wasn't ported to Attach. AttachExtended is the perfect playground to try it out again (but it is not easy...)

@JoséPereda I tried using the old javafxports plugin, I was able to add the admob dependency but the application crushes due to an error. (Something like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string)
